# How to return result to a table or csv type of format from html

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to set up a scrape from a betting site I can run during the NFL season to get the odds into Excel/DB, but as I am very new to python and bs4 I'm running into trouble.

I'm using Python 3.7.4 with BS4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result2 = requests.get("https://www.betfair.com/sport/american-football/nfl-kampe/green-bay-packers-chicago-bears/29202049")
src2 = result2.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')

for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'minimarketview-content'}):
    print(item.text)
```

I would like output to be csv like this:

```
"Green Bay Packers", "2.3", "Chicago Bears", "1.55"
"Green Bay Packers", "1.7","+3,5", "Chicago Bears", "2.0","-3.5"
```

Current result (with big line breaks):

```
Green Bay Packers

2.3

Chicago Bears

1.55

Green Bay Packers

1.7

+3,5

etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't access the site because it's blocked behind the firewall on the public wifi I am on so I can't test the code below, but instead of printing the items, put them into a list. Then take that list and convert to dataframe/table. So something like:

**Note: Still work to be done to clean it up, but this gets you going**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

result2 = requests.get("https://www.betfair.com/sport/american-football/nfl-kampe/green-bay-packers-chicago-bears/29202049")
src2 = result2.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')

data = []
for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'minimarketview-content'}):
    temp_data = [ alpha for alpha in item.text.split('\n') if alpha != '' ] 
    data.append(temp_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
                               0     1                      2              3                          4      5                  6     7
0              Green Bay Packers  11/8          Chicago Bears           8/13                       None   None               None  None
1              Green Bay Packers   3/4                   +3.5  Chicago Bears                      11/10   -3.5               None  None
2                Current Points:  Over                  20/23            +46                      Under  19/20                +46  None
3  Green Bay Packers by 1-13 Pts   2/1  Green Bay Packers 14+            5/1  Chicago Bears by 1-13 Pts    6/4  Chicago Bears 14+  10/3
```

Comment: this is the soup html: https://pastebin.com/fd8XAMYm assuming you can access that.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. on the website there are several different bets - each one has a class 'minimarketview-content'.
I would the item texts from each of these classes passed with commas. and 1 row per class. Does that make sense?

With your code i get this:
0  Green Bay Packers\n\n\n2.3\n\n\n\n\nChicago Be...  ...  Green Bay Packers med 1-13 point\n\n\n3.0\n\n\...

[1 rows x 4 columns]

Comment: Thanks for posting the soup :)

Comment: Ya that makes sense. I was just using your code, assuming it was producing what you posted in Current result (with big line breaks). give me a minute and I'll fix my code (thanks to @QHarr for posting that html for me)

Comment: @mvp1988, just updated above. By the way I LOVE working with sports data. It was actually what I did for my master's dissertation and producing a neural network machine learning model for fantasy sports (NFL)

Comment: Thanks man! Will take a look. I'm looking for the prop pets specifically, and they will all have same structure when they get posted.
Sounds awesome, I love Fantasy.

Next step is to generate batch of URL's for the weeks games, then apply this code to the batch of urls.

Comment: Cool. Sounds good. Eventually, you might want to look at seeing if you can pull that data through API or XHR from the site (I can check later when I get to my home laptop). It would make things a heck of a lot easier, but if you're just starting out with web scrapping, might be a big step to take while learning all this stuff.

Comment: @chitown88 - Yea I literally started yesterday :). Just awesome that people are so willing to help and teach us rooks :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just replace the new line symbol with space?

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'minimarketview-content'}):

        x = item.text.replace('\n',',')
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([x])
```

Edit:
Added save to .csv file.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Is it possible to get a comma between the values - so i can easier parse after?

Result:
 Green Bay Packers   2.3     Chicago Bears   1.55     
   Green Bay Packers   1.7   +3,5   Chicago Bears   2.0   -3,5   
  Nuværende antal points:     Over   1.8   +46   Under   1.9   +46   
   Green Bay Packers med 1-13 point   3.0     Green Bay Packers 14+   6.0     Chicago Bears med 1-13 point   2.5     Chicago Bears 14+   4.33

Comment: I exchanged the space with comma. And I can treat consecutive commas as one delimiter.
Is there an easy way to save to a CSV file?

Comment: Eidited my answer, you have to import csv, and then open the file and save the X to it.